# Is there a way to prevent 2 of the same tkinter screen from opening?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I want to be able to press a button that opens up a new tkinter window. I have got this to work but i have seen that when you press the button again, the same window opens. How do i prevent this?

code:

```
def login_success():
    print('Login success')   #confirmation that Go button works, funtion will change

def login_screen():
    global screen
    root.geometry('300x350')
    root.title('Login')

    global username_login
    global password_login
    username_login = StringVar() #turns global variable into string
    password_login = StringVar()
    

    Label(text = 'TGUP' , bg = 'light blue', width ='300', height = '2', font =('Calibri',13)).pack()
    Label(text = '').pack()
    Button(text = 'Register', height='2',width='30', command=Reg).pack() #opens new window
    Label(text='').pack()
    Label(text = 'Login', fg = 'purple', font=10).pack()
    Label(text = 'Username').pack()
    username_entry1 = Entry(textvariable = username_login, bg='light grey').pack() #entry box for inputs
    Label(text = 'Password').pack()
    password_entry1 = Entry(textvariable = password_login, bg='light grey', show='*').pack()
    Button(text = 'Go', width = '10', height='2', fg='green', command=login_success ).pack()
    Label(text='').pack()
    Button(text='Exit', height='2',width='20', fg='red' ,command=root.destroy).pack()  #destroys window
```

Comment: Please provide the code. It is not possible to know what is wrong unless you give some code

Comment: Use `<tkinter.Button>.config(state="disabled")` to disable a button. You can use `<tkinter.Button>.config(state="normal")` when the user closes the window to enable the button

Comment: @Sujay provided the targeted part of the code.